# getting 404 Method not found error when calling mybusiness google api in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I call mybusiness google api

```
const getLocation = async (userId, accessToken) => {
  if (accessToken) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/${userId}/locations`, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        }
      }).then((res) => resolve(res.json()))
        .catch((e) => reject(e));
    })
  } else {
    Alert.alert('', 'Access token missing')
  }
}
```

getting this error by calling above api:

```
{"error": {"code": 404, "message": "Method not found.", "status": "NOT_FOUND"}}
```

getting accessToken from google singin

passing this config for google signin

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: '12987312978-uiaefh8293kjdsnfkj8w9uekjds.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"],
  forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
  offlineAccess: true,
});
```

Google signin

```
const googleSingin = async () => {
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    await GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then((userInfo) => {
          if (userInfo) {
                const data = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
                console.log('access-token:', data.accessToken);
          }
     })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
```

Comment: It happens because you are trying to interact with the Google My Business API using a non-whitelisted project. can you check is your project is white listed or not ?

Comment: how can I check? thanks for reply

Comment: Go through this link: https://support.knowbe4.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002797527-Whitelisting-by-IP-Address-in-Google-Workspace-Google-Apps